# How to call custom js function on scroll in Dojo OnDemandGrid?

Tags: javascript, dojo, grid

We are using dojo OnDemandGrid. I need to call a js method when I scroll down and more records are loaded in the Grid.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
aspect.after(grid,"dgrid-refresh-complete",function(){

});

grid.on("dgrid-refresh-complete", function(event){

});
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and add some code.

Comment: @MiBrock : Edited the question with what i have done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything exposed per se for this, but you should be able to aspect after the `_processScroll` method, which is what is called in response to the grid's viewport scrolling.

The `_processScroll` method itself determines whether more data needs to be loaded.  If it doesn't need to load anything, its return value should be undefined.